# Angular transform an object in template w/o custom pipe

Tags: angular, angular-template, angular-pipe

I have an issue with transformation. I am listing some users in a p-table like this:

```
<td *ngFor="let col of columns">
  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="col.field">
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'status'">
      {{user[col.field] | titlecase}}
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'roleNames'">
      {{user[col.field]}}
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
      {{user[col.field]}}
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</td>
```

I want to transform roleNames (they look like this: [ADMIN_USER]).
Each user can have multiple roles ([AGENT_USER, CLINIC_USER]).

If I `console.log` the `typeof` inside roleNames case it says it's an object.
And sadly no other pipe can work with objects but keyvalue, but I cannot do an ngFor within the ng-container to be "invisible".

How can I do some magic to these roleNames to become something like: Admin user, Clinic User etc...

Managed to do this w/o a pipe, because I'd not like to make more garbage since it's only used once. However if it'd be used more i'd do a pipe for it.

Solution:

```
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'roleNames'">
          {{sliceRoles(user[col.field]) | titlecase}}
        </ng-container>


sliceRole(roles: object) {
    const formattedRoles = [];
    let finalRoles = '';
    Object.values(roles).forEach((role) => {
      const newRole = role.replace('_', ' ');
      formattedRoles.push(newRole.concat(', '));
    });
    finalRoles = finalRoles.concat(...formattedRoles).slice(0, -2);
    return finalRoles;
  }
```

Comment: "w/o custom pipe" Why?

Comment: Because i am not that experienced to do so.

Comment: It's not that hard. Pipe is just a function which takes a variable and returns another. https://angular.io/guide/pipes